# How to send HTTP request to sails.js + MongoDB with createdAt parameter?

Tags: mongodb, httprequest, sails.js

I am trying to post a query to Sails.js via HTTP POST in order to find records created after a certain point in time.

Using the following syntax works perfectly and gives me back one record with the correct time:

localhost:1337/object?where={"createdAt":"2014-08-19T14:36:16.047Z"}

When trying to add an operator the query does not work any longer giving me no records in the object collection :

localhost:1337/object?where={"createdAt":{">":"2014-08-19T14:36:16.047Z"}}

Due to the fact that the date conversion from ISODate to dateTime works for the exact query I suppose it should also work for the ">" query.

Highly appreciate some help on this one.

Comment: You've checked and made sure there are actually records that fit that criteria?

Comment: Yes I checked the records. The actual problem is that in JSON no datetime format is foreseen and Sails is doing a string comparison with the received ISOString date which does not work. I would expect Sails to make a date conversion from the ISOString for fields that are known to be dates (from the schema or from the fact that createdAt is always a date).

Comment: Acording to sails documentation:
You can do date range queries using the comparison operators.  

```Model.find({ date: { '>': new Date('2/4/2014'), '<': new Date('2/7/2014') } })```. So probably you have to do this in the controller